# connectionstrings does not exist in the current context error

Tags: c#

Hi I have c# console application in which I am trying to use connection strings. For this I need to use

```
using System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
```

But I can see only system.configuration in using statement. So what I did is I add reference to my project by right clicking on my project and then Add reference then Add **system.configuration** to my project.

After I did this also I am not able to see **ConfigurationManager** in my application.

When I did some research on this I got to know that for some people it worked after they add reference and close Visual studio and reopen.

But for me this also dint worked. So any solution for this ??

**Update :**
After struggling with this, If I use every time like this System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[], its working. but its pain to use every time this lengthy line. Is there a solution for this ??

Comment: Can you tell me whether you have added System.Configuration reference to your project or not ?

Comment: @PradipKT Yes that's the first thing I did before posting this post.

Comment: And have you "imported/using" it to your code ?

Answer (score 2):

> Project Properties -> Add reference --> .NET tab -->
>   System.Configuration

In c# , you can only put the using like:

```
using System.Configuration;
```

this using is **not** valid:

```
using System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager;
```

And use it like:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["string"];
```

To get the connection strings in C# use:

```
ConnectionStringSettingsCollection cnnStrings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;
```

You can use that Namespace imports using vb.net like this:

```
Imports System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
```

Also check your target framework is for example, Net 4.0 Framework and not Net 4.0 **Client Profile**

Comment: Hi I cannot see System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager in my .net tab. But I can see System.Configuration and I already have this reference.

Comment: Ah! `Resharper` really made me dumb! It does not let me learn.. ;)

Comment: Yeah enough. Change your using to System.Configuration.

Comment: Updated my answer. I hope you understand better. in c# you only have to write: using System.Configuration. in vb.net you can write System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager

Comment: Hi carlos I followed your step. But connectionStrings is not showing in my intellisense and it is showing it does not exist in current context.

Comment: Have you tried this:   ConnectionStringSettingsCollection cnnStrings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings; having on top: using System.Configuration; only?

Comment: Hi If i use every time like this System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[], its working.

Comment: Put on top of the class: using System.Configuration and then you can use: ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a .config file in your application?

If not, please add one, then you can modify the ConnectionStrings section,

and this error will not show up again.

Comment: Yes I already have file called app.config and I have my coneection string here.

Answer (score 0):

What error are you seeing? If I follow these steps I can see a connection string in a test console app:

Edit App.config to contain the connection string. My App.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="TEST" connectionString="connection details here." />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Add a reference to System.Configuration for the Console application.

Add `"using System.Configuration;"` to the top of Program.cs.

The connection string details should now be available. See the image below for an example assignment:
[image]

Comment: I also followed the exact procedure.I have connection strings in app.config and I am using System.Configuration reference in my application.But not able to use connectionstrings.It is showing context doesn't exist.

Comment: @Raj: Can you post the exact error message and the code that triggers it?