# Using the connectionString in OnConfiguration of DbContext

Tags: c#, .net

Well, I'd like to use my ConnectionString in my onConfiguration of the DBContext:

```
   protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {                
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString); //This is not working so far. Not able to compile
        }
    }
```

What do I have to add to make this working.

Comment: I think that error is clear. U dont have declared field connectionString in your DBContext class.

Comment: Do you want to fetch connection string from appsettings.json and get there dynamicaly? Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score -1):

Here are the docs on configuring the DbContext:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{ 
  protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
  {
   
   optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Test");
  }
}
```

Comment: The name "connectionstring" does not exist in the current context

Comment: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112101/connectionstrings-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context-error